# What does $n \to \infty$ suggest in the context of limit superior (or inferior)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation, limsup-and-liminf

This question is about notations and notations only and it may sound unnecessarily pedantic or nitpicky but I'm kind of curious what does $n \to ∞$ below the $\limsup $ or $\liminf $ notations suggest?

For instance, the limit superior of a sequence $(x_n)$ is denoted by writing $\limsup\limits_{n \to ∞} x_n$ instead of simply writing $\limsup x_n$ (which, I'm aware is an alternative notation).

Now, I could write this question off as "Hey that's just a notation." But what bothers me is that $\limsup x_n$ is simply the greatest limit point of the sequence $(x_n)$ whether or not $n$ is large. Then why write $n \to \infty$, I wonder?

In contrast, writing $\lim\limits_{n \to ∞} x_n = L$ means when $n$ is sufficiently large then $x_m≈L, \, \forall \,m≥n$. But I can't make a similar sense of those notations used for limit superior (or inferior). Thoughts?

Comment: It is still a limit of some subsequence, so maybe that explains it? Maybe also to emphasise the variable $n$.

Comment: Well, the definition is $\displaystyle \limsup_{n \to \infty}x_n := \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\inf_{k \geq n} x_k\right)$, so there is in fact a limit involved. As with limits, you can drop the $n \to \infty$ if there's no chance of ambiguity. An example where you wouldn't want to drop it would be something like $\displaystyle \limsup_{n \to \infty}a_{m,n}$

Comment: If $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence then $\lim \sup x_n$ is shorthand for $\lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n$.  If, however, $\{x_n\}$ is actually a net (when it is better written $\{ x_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ for clarity) then $\alpha \rightarrow \infty$ doesn't actually have a meaning.  So then $\lim \sup x_\alpha$ is the correct way to write it

Comment: Btw, your same argument can be applied to $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}x_n$. After all, when it exists, the limit *is* the limsup (and the liminf), or paraphrasing your language, it's the *only* limit point of the sequence $(x_n)$.

Comment: @Bungo Yes, indeed but it makes sense intuitively both ways. Whether you write it like $\lim\limits_{n \to ∞} x_n$ or $\lim x_n$. Secondly, you can almost always turn around the argument from one thing to other but that is not always helpful. I'm clear on $\lim\limits_{n \to ∞}$ but not on $\limsup\limits_{n \to ∞}$. So I'm using the former to make sense out of the latter. But in this case, I can't make sense out of the former using the latter as I'm not clear on the latter notation to begin with. If that makes any sense, at all haha.

Comment: With sequences (of one variable) the $n \to \infty$ is redundant, as you say, and that's true for both limsup/liminf and lim. But that's not the only context. As with limits, the limsup/liminf concepts also apply to functions of real variables, so for example $\limsup_{x \to 0}f(x)$ is meaningful and the $x \to 0$ is not optional. I guess people use the $n \to \infty$ notation for consistency with the general case, and because it doesn't harm anything to be explicit.

Comment: @Bungo But I like your other comment where you say $\limsup\limits_{n \to ∞} x_n$ is suggestive of the limit $\lim\limits_{n \to ∞} \left( \sup\limits_{m≥n} \right)$. (You kind of mixed up the definition, but that's fine as I know what you meant.)

Comment: Oops yeah, sorry, I gave the definition for $\liminf$ instead of $\limsup$. Thanks for catching that, too late to edit that comment unfortunately.

Comment: @Bungo That is interesting, I didn't know it made sense for functions too. Perhaps you should gather your comments (and if you have any more thoughts on the matter) into an answer. Upvoting comments doesn't give reputation points, sadly.

Comment: Sure, I'll write up a quick answer to summarize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing the comments:

---

For a sequence $(x_n)$, one definition of limsup is
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty}x_n := \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\sup_{k \geq n}x_k\right),$$
so there is in fact a limit involved. As with limits, you can drop the $n \to \infty$ when there's no ambiguity. An example where it would be ambiguous to drop it is
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_{m,n}$$
where $(a_{m,n})$ is a sequence of two variables.

It is worth noting that, as with limits, the limsup/liminf concepts also apply to functions of real variables. For example,
$$\limsup_{x \to 0}f(x) := \lim_{x \to 0}\left(\sup\{f(y) : 0 < |y| < |x|\}\right)$$
Here, the $x\to 0$ cannot be omitted without ambiguity, because it tells us which point we're focusing on.

So to summarize, for sequences of one variable, it's true that the $n \to \infty$ is redundant (both for limsup/liminf and for lim) because there's no other interpretation that makes sense. I think people use the $n \to \infty$ for consistency with the other situations (sequences of multiple variables, functions of a real variable) where similar notation is required. In any case, it doesn't harm anything to be explicit even when not strictly necessary.